# Golang: How to instantiate `struct` by struct name (string)

Tags: struct, go

Not in golang,
we can instantiate class dynamically by class name as

PHP

```php
<?php
class MyKlass {
    public $prop = "foo";
    public function meth() {
        echo "This is my method\n";
        echo "This.prop = {$this->prop}";
    }
}
$class_name = "MyKlass";
$k = new $class_name;
$k->meth();
```

Python

```py
class MyKlass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = "buz"
    def meth(self):
        print("This prop is " + self.prop)
modules = {
    "MyKlass":MyKlass
}
class_name = "MyKlass"
k = modules[class_name]()
k.meth()
```

So in golang,
how to instantiate `struct` by using struct name, which is `string` type?

Comment: As in other languages, this is called "reflection" and there's a package for that : http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/

Comment: Thanks! It is duplicated by this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string.

Comment: This is the obligatory reminder that reflection is much, much slower than using interfaces or repeating some boilerplate code, and tends to make the code much simpler as well. You're better off adapting your program's structure to the differently-structured language than trying to translate your PHP or Python directly.

Comment: Ack, previous comment meant to say interfaces make the code _simpler_ than reflection. For instance, if your `meth` was `HandleRequest(Request, Response)`, you could make that the sole method in a `RequestHandler` [interface](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types), and your `modules` dictionary could map strings to functions that make RequestHandlers. Doesn't require a way to create objects using a string class name directly.