# Trying to convert string to instance variable

Tags: rest, go, controller, resources, revel

I'm new to GO language.
Trying to learn GO by building real web application.
I'm using revel framework.

And here is my resource routes:

```
GET     /resource/:resource                     Resource.ReadAll
GET     /resource/:resource/:id                 Resource.Read
POST    /resource/:resource                     Resource.Create
PUT     /resource/:resource/:id                 Resource.Update
DELETE  /resource/:resource/:id                 Resource.Delete
```

for example:

`GET /resource/users` calls `Resource.ReadAll("users")`

And this is my Resource controller (it's just a dummy actions for now):

```
type Resource struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

type User struct {
    Id int
    Username string
    Password string
}

type Users struct {}

func (u Users) All() string {
        return "All"
}

func (c Resource) ReadAll(resource string) revel.Result {
    fmt.Printf("GET %s", resource)
    model := reflect.New(resource)
    fmt.Println(model.All())
    return nil
}
```

I'm trying get instance of Users struct by converting **resource string** to object to call **All** function.

and the error:

> cannot use resource (type string) as type reflect.Type in argument to
>   reflect.New:  string does not implement reflect.Type (missing Align
>   method)

I'm new to GO please don't judge me :)

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
model := reflect.New(resource)
```

You can't instantiate a type from a string that way. You need to either use a switch there and do stuff depending on the model:

```
switch resource {
case "users":
    model := &Users{}
    fmt.Println(model.All())
case "posts":
    // ...
}
```

Or use `reflect` correctly. Something like:

```
var types = map[string]reflect.Type{
    "users": reflect.TypeOf(Users{}) // Or &Users{}.
}

// ...

model := reflect.New(types[resource])
res := model.MethodByName("All").Call(nil)
fmt.Println(res)
```

Comment: That still won't work because you can't call methods on `interface{}`, (because it has no methods). You'd still need to [type assert](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) it to do it that way, and if you will, there is no point to try and instantiate a type from a string. This is something that would work well in a dynamic language, not in Go.