# Golang: How can I use refect package with exsisting library

Tags: reflection, go

I want to call a function in a existing library from function name.

In golang, just calling method from methodname is OK, because reflect package has (v Value) MethodByName(name string).
But, for calling a method, all method argument should be reflect.Value.

How can I call a function whose argument are not reflect.Value.

```
package main

//-------------------------------
// Example of existing library
//-------------------------------
type Client struct {
    id string
}

type Method1 struct {
    record string
}

// type Method2 struct{}
// ...

// defined at library : do not change
func (c *Client) Method1(d *Method1) {
    d.record = c.id
}

//------------------
// Edit from here
//------------------
func main() {
    // give MethodN from cmd line
    method_name := "Method1"

    // How can I call Method1(* Method1) propery???
    // * Make Method1 instance
    // * Call Method1 function
    //...
    //fmt.Printf("%s record is %s", method_name, d.record)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/6B6-90GTwc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `reflect.Value`s of client and method values with `reflect.ValueOf` and then use `reflect.Value.Call`:

```
methodName := "Method1"

c := &Client{id: "foo"}
m := &Method1{record: "bar"}

args := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(m)}
reflect.ValueOf(c).MethodByName(methodName).Call(args)
fmt.Printf("%s record is %s", methodName, m.record)
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/PT33dqj9Q9.

Comment: > m := &Method1{record: "bar"}   

I need to create instance from methodName, because it shoud work when mehtodName is "Method2".

Comment: An instance of what? You [can't just instantiate types from strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string).

Comment: I see. My question is same as the link. Thank you for giving reference.