# Can map values be variable types?

Tags: dictionary, go

In Golang, the values in map, can they be types ? For example how do I create a map m[string]type such that it can be like this,

```
 m["abc"] = int
 m["def"] = string
 m["ghi"] = structtype ( some structure of type structtype)
```

I need such map because, I have a function which has a string argument and according to that string argument the function creates a variable of a certain type and does some operations. So, if I have a map which maps a string to a type, the function can check that map using the string argument as the key to find out which type of variable it needs to create.

Comment: types are not values, but you can use a zero value of a type, or `reflect.Type` values.

Comment: You will need to become very familiar with the `reflect` package.

Comment: RayfenWindspear and @JimB  so the map should be defined as m[string]interface{} ?

Comment: @user1851006 `map[string]reflect.Type` I swear I've answered this question before, but I can't seem to find it....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to store a Type in a map and use it later to instantiate an object in Go lang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124427/is-it-possible-to-store-a-type-in-a-map-and-use-it-later-to-instantiate-an-objec)

Comment: Note that the question above is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sounds like you need `map[string]reflect.Type`

```
val := map[string]reflect.Type{}{}

val["int"] = reflect.TypeOf(int(0))
pointer_to_new_item := reflect.New(val["int"])
```

If you need a non-pointer value you then use `Indirect`:

```
new_item := reflect.Indirect(pointer_to_new_item)
```

Using reflect to create a value will give you a `reflect.Value`, which you then need to unpack the actual value you want from using other reflect functions. See [The reflect documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect) for more info.

Keep in mind that `reflect.New` only makes simple types, structures, etc. If you need channels, maps, or slices there are other, similar functions that work like the `make` builtin.

Comment: in your example, instead of int, if it is a struct type, do I have to create a random struct variable of that type to  reflect it's value ?

Comment: Yes, but you only have to do it when populating the map, so it only has to be done once.

Comment: You must also note, that the code in this answer will give you a `reflect.Value`, not an `int`. There is extra `reflect` stuff involved to make it an actual `int` or `struct` or whatever it is.

Comment: Very true, that is one of the reasons I made sure to link to the docs. I should probably have put that in the answer. I'll edit it.

Comment: @MiloChristiansen It's the reason I flagged as a duplicate to one I answered that was the exact same question. You answer is good and nicely concise, but I wanted to make sure to link to other resources as well.

Comment: I just realized that what I get is not a struct but an interface which I need to convert into the struct. That's just meaningless because if I knew the struct , then I'd directly define a variable instead of using all this.

Comment: Well, sadly this is the best you can do. If you don't know the struct you need to use reflection to access it anyway, so it is not a problem in practice.