# Generic function with variable input/output types

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

Just playing with aws sdk for go. When listing resources of different types I tend to have alot of very similar functions like the two in the example bellow.
Is there a way to rewrite them as one generic function that will return a specific type depending on what is passed on as param?

Something like:

```
func generic(session, funcToCall, t, input) (interface{}, error) {}
```

currently I have to do this (functionality is the same just types change):

```
func getVolumes(s *session.Session) ([]*ec2.Volume, error) {

    client := ec2.New(s)

    t := []*ec2.Volume{}
    input := ec2.DescribeVolumesInput{}

    for {
        result, err := client.DescribeVolumes(&input)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        t = append(t, result.Volumes...)

        if result.NextToken != nil {
            input.NextToken = result.NextToken
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return t, nil
}

func getVpcs(s *session.Session) ([]*ec2.Vpc, error) {

    client := ec2.New(s)

    t := []*ec2.Vpc{}
    input := ec2.DescribeVpcsInput{}

    for {
        result, err := client.DescribeVpcs(&input)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        t = append(t, result.Vpcs...)

        if result.NextToken != nil {
            input.NextToken = result.NextToken
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return t, nil
}
```

Comment: Use an interface!

Comment: with the reflection package you can create new functions at runtime.They can take any input, output type, just define it. see reflect.FuncOf and reflect.MakeFunc.

Comment: thank you @mh-cbon was just looking at reflection but its not as simple as it looks :)

Comment: @Abdullah , an example would be much more valuable then short comment.

Comment: reflect looks impressive but it only requires practice to master it.

Comment: If your functions are really that similar to each other, you can easily generate their bodies (with any text processing tool of your choosing. Go has some built-in). And if you do that, then you don't care about all the duplication.

Comment: forthe latter see https://blog.golang.org/generate i think some good projects exists to helps around that, check on github.

Comment: this is interesting concept @SergioTulentsev, was just looking at aws-sdk-go source and looks like this is exactly how they generate the go code for the sdk based on json models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only deal with functions it is possible to use the reflect package to generate functions at runtime.

Using the object type (Volume, Vpc) it is possible to derive all subsequents information to provide a fully generic implementation that is really dry, at the extent at the being more complex and slower.

It is untested, you are welcome to help in testing and fixing it, but something like this should put you on the track

https://play.golang.org/p/mGjtYVG2OZS

The registry idea come from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23031445/4466350

for reference the golang documentation of the reflect package is at https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", getter(Volume{}))
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", getter(Vpc{}))
}

type DescribeVolumesInput struct{}
type DescribeVpcs struct{}

type Volume struct{}
type Vpc struct{}

type Session struct{}

type Client struct{}

func New(s *Session) Client { return Client{} }

var typeRegistry = make(map[string]reflect.Type)

func init() {
    some := []interface{}{DescribeVolumesInput{}, DescribeVpcs{}}
    for _, v := range some {
        typeRegistry[fmt.Sprintf("%T", v)] = reflect.TypeOf(v)
    }
}

var errV = errors.New("")
var errType = reflect.ValueOf(&errV).Elem().Type()
var zeroErr = reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem())
var nilErr = []reflect.Value{zeroErr}

func getter(of interface{}) interface{} {

    outType := reflect.SliceOf(reflect.PtrTo(reflect.TypeOf(of)))
    fnType := reflect.FuncOf([]reflect.Type{reflect.TypeOf(new(Session))}, []reflect.Type{outType, errType}, false)
    fnBody := func(input []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {

        client := reflect.ValueOf(New).Call(input)[0]

        t := reflect.MakeSlice(outType, 0, 0)
        name := fmt.Sprintf("Describe%TsInput", of)
        descInput := reflect.New(typeRegistry[name]).Elem()

        mName := fmt.Sprintf("Describe%Ts", of)
        meth := client.MethodByName(mName)
        if !meth.IsValid() {
            return []reflect.Value{
                t,
                reflect.ValueOf(fmt.Errorf("no such method %q", mName)),
            }
        }
        for {
            out := meth.Call([]reflect.Value{descInput.Addr()})
            if len(out) > 0 {
                errOut := out[len(out)-1]
                if errOut.Type().Implements(errType) && errOut.IsNil() == false {
                    return []reflect.Value{t, errOut}
                }
            }
            result := out[1]
            fName := fmt.Sprintf("%Ts", of)
            if x := result.FieldByName(fName); x.IsValid() {
                t = reflect.AppendSlice(t, x)
            } else {
                return []reflect.Value{
                    t,
                    reflect.ValueOf(fmt.Errorf("field not found %q", fName)),
                }
            }

            if x := result.FieldByName("NextToken"); x.IsValid() {
                descInput.FieldByName("NextToken").Set(x)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        return []reflect.Value{t, zeroErr}
    }
    fn := reflect.MakeFunc(fnType, fnBody)
    return fn.Interface()
}
```

Comment: Code generation might be easier than reflection :)

Comment: yeah, when it works for your use case ; ) in this case it might, provide your answer!

Comment: I would have, but I've had a few too many beers tonight. Maybe tomorrow :)

Comment: @mh-cbon , very nice and complete answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Proxying 3rd party API, is quite simple to implement with
go, here is how' it got implemented with endly e2e test runner [AWS proxy](https://github.com/viant/endly/blob/master/system/cloud/aws/proxy.go)

I would say that AWS API is perfect candidate for proxying, as long as reflection performance price is not an issue.

Some other 3rd party  API like [kubernetes](https://github.com/viant/endly/blob/master/system/kubernetes/shared/proxy.go)
 are much more challenging, but still quite easy to proxy with go, which is a combination of reflection and code generation: