# grpc protobuf create new struct with string

Tags: go

I'm using micro framework to develop my new project, and I have finished the GRPC work. But now, I need to write the gateway to interacting with the frontend. I don't really want to write repetitive code, and I find some code in `pb.go` file.

the code is defined some struct and init function. like below:

```
type AuthLoginReq struct {
    Username             string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=username,proto3" json:"username,omitempty"`
    Password             string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=password,proto3" json:"password,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

func init() {
    proto.RegisterType((*AuthLoginReq)(nil), "device.info.provider.service.AuthLoginReq")
}
```

Meanwhile, I found this article [is there a way to create an instance of a struct from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string).

Fortunately. pb file already defines it for me, but protoc auto generate file is defined nil pointer `(*AuthLoginReq)(nil)`.

api.go

```
        qiniuType := proto.MessageType("device.info.provider.service.AuthLoginReq")

        pbValue := reflect.New(qiniuType)

        pbStruct := pbValue.Elem().Interface()
```

When I change pbSturct is not really change, because is nil pointer

```
ctx.ShouldBind(&pbStruct)
```

`pbStruct` is already change. but `pbValue` is not change.

How do I change `pbValue`?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway.  Perhaps you can leverage this project, or get some ideas from it.

Comment: @sberry This way need to change proto file and Sacrifice flexibility . Maybe I should find answer in micro api . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with `reflect` enough to know that it's impossible, but it's definitely not obvious how to do it. You might find that setting up your own registry will be easier:

```golang
    registry := map[string]func() interface{}{
        "AuthLoginReq": func() interface{} {
            return &AuthLoginReq{}
        },
    }

    i := registry["AuthLoginReq"]()
    a := i.(*AuthLoginReq)
    a.Username = "root"

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/CDIIF69CpUd